# Float in var bug?

Tags: c++, variables

I use this to mesure elapsed time :

```
const clock_t begin_time = clock();
// code here

cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   //return 1.234

float var = ( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << var;                                                //return 1
```

Please explain me i don't understand what is going on.

**EDIT :** 
why the printed var doesn't have the ".234" ?

Comment: Please explain, we don't understand what you're asking. What value do you get and what value are you expecting? why do you think the value is wrong?

Comment: `clock_t` is an integral type, so the second expression performs a integer division. First one is a floating point division (as per the cast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression:

```
float( clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

converts the subsexpression `clock() - begin_time` to a floating-point value, which then means that the whole expression corresponds to a floating-point division (the result of which is `1.234f` in your example).

In the second expression:

```
( clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

all arguments are of integral type, thus an integer division is performed. The result of which is an integer value (in your example `1`). Only later is the result converted to float (`1.0f`) to be assigned to the floating-point variable `var`.

If you want to store the result in `float` variable `var` you can use:

```
float var = float( clock() - begin_time ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << var;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I can't upvote you but thanks a lot ^_^